# too much gap between bootstrap rows when used with full page js in mobile view.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I have used fullpage js with bootstrap in my website.In [here](http://forestpin.azurewebsites.net/analytics.html) I have used `col-md-6` class in the middle sections. It works as expected in desktop view. However when I go to mobile view, it displays a large gap between rows in each section. Same is done in this [page](http://forestpin.azurewebsites.net/index.html) but it does not display a gap between rows(works as expected). In fact I added an extra gap because rows were too close(I used `col-md-4`). How can I fix this issue and what is the cause the for this large gap? thanks!!

Comment: I don't know fullpage.js but I think bootstrap is not the issue here. `<div class="section fp-section fp-table" style="height: 535px;">` Your `div` with `fp-section` class has fixed height of 535px for mobile view.

Comment: fixed height comes from `element.style` and it changes based on the view port height. If you open dev tools and change the height of the mobile view and reload the page, it'll show a different height. This is the same with the second example in the question which works as expected.